# Converting from hours and minutes to total minutes in Python

Tags: python, parsing, pandas, time, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a column of time strings in hours and minutes (e.g. 1 hour 8 mins). Some cells are only minutes (e.g. 47 mins).
I'm trying to convert from this format to just the integer value of the total number of minutes (e.g. 1 hour 8 mins would be 68).

I tried hard coding it but am having trouble with this as I am relatively new to Python.
Is there a library that would be able to help me with this?

```
In [10]: df_times = pd.DataFrame(times)
         df_times.columns = ["times"]
         df_times
Out[10]:       times
        0      31 mins
        1      1 hour 28 mins
        2      1 hour 1 min
        3      1 min
        ...    ...
        22849  ERROR
        22850  7 mins


In [11]: (pd.to_timedelta(df_times["times"].str.replace('mins','min')).dt.total_seconds()//60).astype(int)
ValueError: unit abbreviation w/o a number
```

And when I use errors="coerce":

```
In [12]: (pd.to_timedelta(df_times["times"].str.replace('mins','min'), errors="coerce").dt.total_seconds()//60).astype(int)
ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [pandas.to_timedelta()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and [Series.dt.total_seconds()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) methods:

```
In [244]: df
Out[244]:
                  time
0        1 hour 8 mins
1              47 mins
2  10 hours 12 minutes
3                1 min

In [245]: (pd.to_timedelta(df.time.str.replace('mins', 'min'))
     ...:    .dt.total_seconds()//60).astype(int)
     ...:
Out[245]:
0     68
1     47
2    612
3      1
Name: time, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Would I have to use a for loop apply this to all? Sorry I'm very new to coding. Also where did the 'dt' and 'total_seconds' come from? Thanks!

Comment: @Heather, no, you don't need any loops - `pd.to_timedelta()` is a "vectorized" function which will be applied on the whole series - see example in my answer. I've added a link to `.dt.total_seconds()` documentation...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I seem to be getting a ValueError: unit abbreviation w/o a number.

Comment: @Heather, can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I forgot to mention that some cells have "error" in them instead of a time. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Sure! I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example of code. Thanks!

Comment: `.astype(int)` causes this error message when it tries to convert `NaN` (or `NaT`) to `int`. So you will have to replace NaN's with some integer numbers or remove this part `.astype(int)` and to live with `float` dtype and NaN's - it's your choice

Comment: I have managed to fix it by dealing with the "ERROR" strings that couldn't be converted to integers and turning them to 0s. Thank you very much for your help!